# Angular unit testing terminal error (Cannot read properties of null)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to write unit tests with Angular. But I encountered the terminal error I shared in the image.

I want not to get the error in the terminal and the test to be successful. Spec and component files:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzjXn.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRt2Q.png)

Comment: Please update the question with the code as text (not an image of the code).

Comment: What's the error you encounter on the terminal?